# Content of post does not end up in "ShareThis" mail

Tags: email

I am using [the ShareThis plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/) in my blog. When I click on the email tab and send a mail to my friend, only the post title and post link is included in the mail. Contents are not showing up in the mail.

What can I do to change this?

Answer (score 2):

One year ago [a support employee wrote](http://forums.sharethis.com/topic.php?id=361#post-1456) that "as of right now, the only fields that will show up in an email share is the link title and URL." I don't know whether this is still the case.

But I doubt that ShareThis would ever send the whole contents of the post via mail. I would imagine a webmaster would prefer the receiver of the mail to visit the site instead of just reading everything in the mail.

ShareThis does document [some Open Graph tags](http://help.sharethis.com/customization/share-properties), including `og:description`. Can you try that and tell us whether they end up in the mail?

Comment: Can i know if there is any other plugin where content of post also shows up in the mail while sharing to a friend?

Comment: @scn4u: There are probably plugins that do this, I suggest you ask a new question for that. You can [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to indicate it "solved" your initial problem.